# How to write custom UIViewController initialiser with property in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to write my own UIVC initializer:

```
let person: Person

    init(withPerson person: Person) {
        self.person = person
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
```

but in my coordinator I have this line:

```
func getViewController() -> UIViewController? {
        return ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
    }
```

and it causes a crash with error:

```
 Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(nibName:bundle:)' for class 'ViewController'
```

when I try to add:

```
override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
    }
```

it rises an error with:

`Property 'self.person' not initialized at super.init call`

is there a way how I can fix the crash?

Comment: Could you give more code, so that the error is reproducible please?

Comment: Your custom initialiser needs to call one of the designated `UIViewController` Initialisers. You will need to pass the nib name and bundle to your custom initialiser as well as the person, set the person and the call the designated initialiser with the nibname and bundle parameters.

Answer (score 0):

```
init(withPerson person: Person) {
    self.person = person
    super.init (nibName: "ViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `super.init(nibName:bundle:)` instead of `super.init()` as it's a designated initializer.

If you specify nil for the nibName parameter and you do not override the loadView() method, the view controller searches for a nib file as described [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621487-nibname).

```
init(withPerson person: Person) {
    self.person = person
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
}
```